# Terraform AWS: Question on resource "aws_networkfirewall_firewall". Incorrect attribute value type

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

The output of firewall_subnet_ids is:

```
firewall_subnet_ids = [
  tolist([
    "subnet-0579947678d######",
    "subnet-091417fd3a5######",
    "subnet-0165710e220######",
    "subnet-00afaa21ad6######",
    "subnet-0712cac718c######",
    "subnet-0d361a8d737######",
  ]),
]
```

At line 29, subnet_id = subnet_mapping.value

it complains Inappropriate value for attribute "subnet_id": string required.
I use for_each loop through the firewall subnet IDs. Do not understand why it compains "Incorrect attribute value type"

As follows is the code:

```
terraform {
  # The configuration for this backend will be filled in by Terragrunt
  backend "s3" {}
}

locals {

  tags = {
    Branch        = var.cluster_name
    ProvisionedBy = "Terraform"
    Environment   = var.environment
  }

  networkfirewall_endpoints = { for i in aws_networkfirewall_firewall.anfw.firewall_status[0].sync_states : i.availability_zone => i.attachment[0].endpoint_id }
}

resource "aws_networkfirewall_firewall" "anfw" {
  name                              = "anfw-${var.cluster_name}"
  firewall_policy_arn               = aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy.anfw_policy.arn
  firewall_policy_change_protection = false
  subnet_change_protection          = false

  vpc_id = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.vpc_id
  dynamic "subnet_mapping" {
    #for_each = toset(data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.firewall_subnet_ids)
    for_each = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.firewall_subnet_ids

    content {
      subnet_id = subnet_mapping.value
    }
  }

  tags = local.tags
}

output "vpc_id" {
  value    = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.vpc_id
}

output "firewall_subnet_ids" {
  value    = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.firewall_subnet_ids
}
```

As follows are the errors:

```
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on main.tf line 29, in resource "aws_networkfirewall_firewall" "anfw":
│   29:       subnet_id = subnet_mapping.value
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "subnet_id": string required.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs because a `list(list(string))` type variable used as the parameter value to `for_each` results in the lambda scope iterator variable `subnet_mapping.value` being of type `list(string)`, and instead a `string` type is required for `subnet_id`. You can either fix the data in the remote state:

```
firewall_subnet_ids = tolist([
  "subnet-0579947678d######",
  "subnet-091417fd3a5######",
  "subnet-0165710e220######",
  "subnet-00afaa21ad6######",
  "subnet-0712cac718c######",
  "subnet-0d361a8d737######",
]),
```

or convert the type within the `dynamic` block by accessing the zeroth element of the single element list:

```
for_each = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.firewall_subnet_ids[0]
```